# Existence of Laplace transform of $\frac{\cos (at)}{t}$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

> Find the Laplace transform of $\dfrac{\sin(at)}{t}$.  Does $\mathcal L\left[\dfrac{\cos(at)}{t}\right]$ exist?

I've found the Laplace transform $\mathcal L\left[\dfrac{\sin(at)}{t}\right]$.  But I'm having trouble with the division of $t$ method for $\dfrac{\cos(at)}{t}$ and couldn't find the right answer.

Comment: Yes you got it right

Comment: Is this a well-defined transform?

Comment: Actually the question is to find whether it exist or not.the original question is like this

Comment: Actually the question is to find whether it exist or not.the original question is like this....find Laplace transform of [sin(at)/t].does L.T of [cos(at)/t] exist?

Comment: http://mathfaculty.fullerton.edu/mathews/c2003/laplacetransform/LaplaceMultDivMod/Images/LaplaceMultDivMod_gr_16.gif

Answer (score 1):

> Use:
>
> $$\frac{\cos\left(\text{k}t\right)}{t}=\sum_{\text{n}=0}^\infty\frac{\left(-1\right)^\text{n}\left(\text{k}t\right)^{2\text{n}}}{t\left(2\text{n}\right)!}$$

---

So, we get:

$$\mathcal{L}_t\left[\frac{\cos\left(\text{k}t\right)}{t}\right]_{\left(\text{s}\right)}:=\int_0^\infty e^{-\text{s}t}\times\frac{\cos\left(\text{k}t\right)}{t}\space\text{d}t=\int_0^\infty e^{-\text{s}t}\sum_{\text{n}=0}^\infty\frac{\left(-1\right)^\text{n}\left(\text{k}t\right)^{2\text{n}}}{t\left(2\text{n}\right)!}\space\text{d}t=$$
$$\sum_{\text{n}=0}^\infty\frac{\left(-1\right)^\text{n}}{\left(2\text{n}\right)!}\int_0^\infty e^{-\text{s}t}\times\frac{\left(\text{k}t\right)^{2\text{n}}}{t}\space\text{d}t=\sum_{\text{n}=0}^\infty\frac{\left(-1\right)^\text{n}\text{k}^{2\text{n}}}{\left(2\text{n}\right)!}\int_0^\infty e^{-\text{s}t}\times\frac{t^{2\text{n}}}{t}\space\text{d}t=$$
$$\sum_{\text{n}=0}^\infty\frac{\left(-1\right)^\text{n}\text{k}^{2\text{n}}}{\left(2\text{n}\right)!}\int_0^\infty e^{-\text{s}t}t^{2\text{n}-1}\space\text{d}t$$

Now, use when $\Re\left[\text{s}\right]>0\space\wedge\space\color{red}{\Re\left[\text{n}\right]>0}$:

$$\int_0^\infty e^{-\text{s}t}t^{2\text{n}-1}\space\text{d}t=\text{s}^{-2\text{n}}\Gamma\left(2\text{n}\right)$$